Static variables in Visual Studio 2022 throws error
I am trying to declare a static variable in VS 2022 in a console app.
TreeNode prev = null;
static TreeNode treeToDoublyList(TreeNode root)
{
    TreeNode dummy = new TreeNode(0, null, null);
    prev = dummy;
}

 public class TreeNode
 {
     public int val;
     public TreeNode left;
     public TreeNode right;
     public TreeNode(int val = 0, TreeNode left = null, TreeNode right = null)
     {
         this.val = val;
         this.left = left;
         this.right = right;
     }
 }

I keep getting error, a static local function cannot contain a reference to prev.
Not sure what am I missing?

A static function can't access non-static members. Make prev static, too: static TreeNode prev = null;

it doesn't allow me to do that. I get the modifier static is not valid for this item

Please create a [mre].

I have updated the ticket with min code needed for console app

Why are you trying to access prev (an instance member) from treeToDoublyList (a static member)?

I suspect the issue you're running into is because your console app is using Top Level statements.
See: Top Level Statements
When creating a new application (with Visual Studio, at least) you have the option to turn this off:

What does this mean?
Effectively, you're trying to write all of this code inside of your Main() function of your console application, and that's why you're unable to mark prev as static to allow it to be used in the treeToDoublyList function.
As an example, if you had created your application without top level statements it would have looked like this:
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}

and then you could have added your code, the way you're trying to, and it would have looked like this:
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static TreeNode prev = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }

        static TreeNode treeToDoublyList(TreeNode root)
        {
            TreeNode dummy = new TreeNode(0, null, null);
            prev = dummy;

            return dummy;
        }

        public class TreeNode
        {
            public int val;
            public TreeNode left;
            public TreeNode right;
            public TreeNode(int val = 0, TreeNode left = null, TreeNode right = null)
            {
                this.val = val;
                this.left = left;
                this.right = right;
            }
        }
    }
}

